# Updating a DynanoDB from LAMBDA trigger

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I was trying to update my table using a lambda trigger with some values whenever a `MODIFY` event occurs on the table but even though the function is triggered the update query does not run and the changes are not reflected in the dynamodb, and `CloudWatch` shows no error logs regarding updating I have provided my Lambda with `AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess` and `AWSLambdaDynamoDBExecutionRole` permissions . Code is not working for updating.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// extra
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = async (event , context , callback) => {
    // TODO implement
    
    event.Records.forEach((record) => {
        console.log('Stream record: ', JSON.stringify(record, null, 2));
        // logic to find insert type / modify type 
        //if(record.eventName == 'MODIFY' || record.eventName == 'INSERT'){
        if(record.eventName == 'MODIFY'){
             // extract student id, and marks from event itself (save I/O)
            console.log("Printing new image values",JSON.stringify(record.dynamodb.NewImage,null,2));
             // modify the same record once new value is calculated
             
             //############# code for pushing to DynamoDB #################
                 var params = {
                 TableName:'my-table name',
                 Key:{
                 "student_id": 'abc_123'
    },
    UpdateExpression: "set score1 = :r",
    ExpressionAttributeValues:{
        ":r":88
         },
    ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
};

console.log("Updating the item...");
docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to update item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("UpdateItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});

             //############# end of code ###############
        }
        
    });
    
    console.log(event);
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(event),
    };
    
    
    
    return response;
};
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thank you for your help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using [async handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async) I think the issue is that your function completes before handler's body has a chance to run.

One way to rectify this is through the use of `Promise` technique as shown in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async).

Comment: thank you for your answer!! Just wanted to ask a trailing question, is it good practice to use non-async handlers in the lambda, since as a quick fix I removed async and the function worked for me hence the question is it a right way to deal with it or `Promise` is the way to go?
thank you so much for your help !!

Comment: @AkshatTulsani No problem. I don't have any fixed opinion about this. Async handlers are newer, so I guess this what will be used more and more in future.